# Bundler conflict requirements for the Ruby version

Tags: ruby, installation, bundler, rbenv

I installed the `rbenv` but when try to execute this command
`bundle install --path vendor/bundle` I got an error.

Error:

```
  Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby (~> 2.3.7.0)

    github-pages (~> 212) was resolved to 212, which depends on
      jekyll-feed (= 0.15.1) was resolved to 0.15.1, which depends on
        Ruby (>= 2.4.0)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What part of the error message confuses you? It's saying you either need a newer version of ruby (2.4+) or an older version of github-pages. (I think [207](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages/versions/207) is the latest supporting ruby 2.3.)

Comment: Perhaps a key point that might (??) be confusing you is: `~> 2.3.7.0` does **not** mean "greater than or equal to `2.3.7.0`. It means `2.3.7.0 <= version < 2.3.8`. So, you have explicitly specified a version constraint **NOT** to use ruby `v2.4.0`.

Comment: I see. Sorry I'm really new to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the error is saying you have 2 options, upgrade `ruby` to a higher version or downgrade the `github pages`, you mentioned you are using `rbenv` which is very useful for this scenario. All you need to do is upgrade your ruby version. Go to your project folder and open a terminal then you can do something as follow:

`rbenv install x.y.z`, where x.y.z is the ruby version you want to install (e.g. 2.4.0), after that all you need to do is specify which version of ruby do you want to use in that project, so in the same terminal run: `rbenv local x.y.z`. That's it you should be able to run `bundle install`.

A couple of notes:

- Remember to update your gemfile with the proper ruby version (after upgrade)
- If you want to install your gems in a particular path and you are using bundle >= 2 (to check gem version: gem list | grep bundle), you should use a configuration file instead of specify the path in the command. Create a .bundle folder in your root directory and add a file called config, then in such file add the path (e.g. BUNDLE_PATH: ./vendor/bundle)

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile you have the listed

```
Ruby (~> 2.3.7.0)
github-pages (~> 212)
```

github-pages 212 depends on jekyll-feed 0.15.1, which requires ruby 2.4.

To use github-pages 212, you'll need to upgrade to ruby 2.4+, alternatively, downgrade github-pages to an older version that also supports 2.3

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. How do I upgrade ruby 2.4+ and also downgrade github-pages?

Comment: No need to do both, they're alternatives. You only need to upgrade ruby OR downgrade github-pages. The easier option is just to downgrade github-pages to 202 (I think this should work), better option would be to upgrade ruby, but that sometimes has a few more steps involved and will depend on your environment.